# Sumar todos los valores de una columna con jQuery o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Como puedo sumar todos los valores de cada columna y mostrar su total debajo (en su celda respectiva de totales) utilizando jQuery o JavaScript?

Los datos los estoy obteniendo dinamicamente con laravel.

Esta es la tabla en la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla html:

```html
<table class="table text-center table-width mb-0" id="carterasDatas">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Departamento</th>
        <th>Municipio</th>
        <th>Capital Invertido</th>
        <th>Capital+Interés</th>
        <th>Total Amortización</th>
        <th>Total Saldo</th>
        <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
        <tr class="dataColumn">
            <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
            <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>

            //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
            <td class="amountCartera">Q{{$cartera->monto}}</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">Q{{$cartera->montoInteres}}</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">Q{{$cartera->amortizacion}}}</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">Q{{$cartera->saldo}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{route('carteras.show', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-success" title="VER CARTERA"><i class="far fa-eye f-18"></i></a>
                <a href="{{route('carteras.edit', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" title="EDITAR CARTERA"><i class="far fa-edit f-18"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#carterasModal{{$cartera->id}}" title="ELIMINAR CARTERA"> <i class="fas fa-trash f-18"></i> </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td colspan="4"><b>TOTALES</b> </td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Puedes agregarle una clase a las columnas numericas y asi poder seleccionarlas para sumar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tus celdas no tienes un `id` para sumarlas puedes emplear su posición, lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código:

Luego te recomiendo que pongas los totales en un `<tfoot>` para diferenciarlos de las celdas a sumar en el `<tbody>`:

```js
  var cinv=0;
  var cint=0;
  var tta=0;
  var tts=0;
  
  function sumar() {
    elementos=[...$('tbody td')];
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i +=9) {
      cinv+=+elementos[i+4].textContent;
      cint+=+elementos[i+5].textContent;
      tta+=+elementos[i+6].textContent;
      tts+=+elementos[i+7].textContent;
    }
    totales = [...$('tfoot td')];
    totales[1].textContent=cinv;
    totales[2].textContent=cint;
    totales[3].textContent=tta;
    totales[4].textContent=tts;
  }
  
  sumar();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table text-center table-width mb-0" border=1 id="carterasDatas">
<thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Departamento</th>
    <th>Municipio</th>
    <th>Capital Invertido</th>
    <th>Capital+Interés</th>
    <th>Total Amortización</th>
    <th>Total Saldo</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>

        //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
        <td>200</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('carteras.show', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-success" title="VER CARTERA"><i class="far fa-eye f-18"></i></a>
            <a href="{{route('carteras.edit', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" title="EDITAR CARTERA"><i class="far fa-edit f-18"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#carterasModal{{$cartera->id}}" title="ELIMINAR CARTERA"> <i class="fas fa-trash f-18"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
        <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>

        //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
        <td>200</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{route('carteras.show', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-success" title="VER CARTERA"><i class="far fa-eye f-18"></i></a>
            <a href="{{route('carteras.edit', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" title="EDITAR CARTERA"><i class="far fa-edit f-18"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#carterasModal{{$cartera->id}}" title="ELIMINAR CARTERA"> <i class="fas fa-trash f-18"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td colspan="4"><b>TOTALES</b> </td>
        <td class="total">Q</td>
        <td class="total">Q</td>
        <td class="total">Q</td>
        <td class="total">Q</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Este es solo un ejemplo, si solo usas la parte de JQuery te funcionará igual.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando jQuery lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
var totalMonto = 0;
var totalInteres = 0;
var totalAmortizacion = 0;
var totalSaldo = 0;

  $("#carterasDatas tbody tr").each(function(){
     
     totalMonto = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(4).html()) + totalMonto ;
     totalInteres = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(5).html()) + totalInteres;
     totalAmortizacion = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(6).html()) + totalAmortizacion;
     totalSaldo = parseFloat($(this).find("td").eq(7).html()) + totalSaldo;
     
  })
  
  $("#carterasDatas tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(1).html("Q" + totalMonto);
  $("#carterasDatas tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(2).html("Q" + totalInteres);
  $("#carterasDatas tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(3).html("Q" + totalAmortizacion);
  $("#carterasDatas tfoot tr").first().find("td").eq(4).html("Q" + totalSaldo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table text-center table-width mb-0" id="carterasDatas">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Departamento</th>
        <th>Municipio</th>
        <th>Capital Invertido</th>
        <th>Capital+Interés</th>
        <th>Total Amortización</th>
        <th>Total Saldo</th>
        <th>Opciones</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
  
        <tr class="dataColumn">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Nombre 1</td>
            <td>Departamento 1</td>
            <td>Municipio 1</td>

            //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
            <td class="amountCartera">100</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">20</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">50</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">30</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="dataColumn">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Nombre 2</td>
            <td>Departamento 2</td>
            <td>Municipio 2</td>

            //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
            <td class="amountCartera">50</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">10</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">30</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">40</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        
              <tr class="dataColumn">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Nombre 3</td>
            <td>Departamento 3</td>
            <td>Municipio 3</td>

            //-----------AQUI SE TOMAN LAS CANTIDADES------------
            <td class="amountCartera">200</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">80</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">50</td>
            <td class="amountCartera">60</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td colspan="4"><b>TOTALES</b> </td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td class="total">Q</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Básicamente estarías recorriendo cada fila del tbody o cuerpo de la tabla mediante la función [each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), luego para cada fila, encuentras la columna utilizando la función [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) y luego como cada fila tiene varias columnas utilizas la función [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) para especificar la columna donde se encuentra el valor que deseas sumar (pasandole a la función eq() el indice de la columna específica).